# Gmail API Python Plain Text is Not Wrapping in Body of Email

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

When I send an email the plain text is not wrapping. I read that you can't have more than 80 characters in a line or Gmail automatically makes a break and it makes the text look horrible on a phone.  I put 'html' as second parameter in MIMETEXT().  This wraps the text, but does not include any Python escape characters. I can't figure out how to make line breaks?

Code:
I set MIMEText with 'html' parameter and this seems to wrap text, but in a block with out any of the Python escape characters being used.

```
def CreateMessageHtml(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    msg = MIMEText(message_text,'html')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_string())}
```

Issue is in the message_text, not sure how to create a line break because \n is not working.

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        to = row['Email']
        sender = "sender"
        subject = "subject"
        dedent_text = '''Hello {}, \n
        Thank you for attending our last meeting.  We would 
        like to see you again at our next event.'''.format(row['First'])
    message_text = textwrap.dedent(dedent_text).strip()
    SendMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A multiline string should include line breaks automatically

Answer (score 1):

In the function CreateMessageHtml the MIMEText object takes a subtype, which is 'HTML'.  From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText

class email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text[, _subtype[, _charset]])
Module: email.mime.text

A subclass of MIMENonMultipart, the MIMEText class is used to create MIME objects of major type text. _text is the string for the payload. _subtype is the minor type and defaults to plain.

Based on this you need to pass in a HTML formatted string.  So I changed the dedent_text in the main function to:

```
dedent_text='''Hello {},
<p> Thank you for attending our last meeting.</P>
<p>We would like to see you again at our next 
event.</p>'''.format(row['First'])
```

Now the text wraps on a phone with line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using triple quotes `""" TEXT """` instead of triple apostrophes. Tried this:

```
mytext = """I'm going \n down down \n down """
print mytext
```

and the output was:

```
I'm going 
 down down 
 down
```